# HTML Forms & control names

Tags: html, forms, file-upload, file-io

So I was having issues with the form / hidden iframe file upload technique and spent several days trying to figure out why files wouldn't upload until finally figuring out what the issue was.

When I am building the form dynamically, I insert the file input element as a child of the form:

```
<input type="file" id="file-select-input" />
```

... and I had something like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="file-select-form" target="select-file-iframe" method="POST" action="/upload/">
    <div id="file-select-button" class="">
        <input type="file" id="file-select-input" />
    </div>
</form>
<iframe style="display: none" id="select-file-iframe" src="javascript:false;" name="select-file-iframe"></iframe>
```

It turns out that when I submit the above form, the input file information was not being sent. The reason for this, is that I didn't have the `name` attribute specified on the file input element. So when I changed it to this:

```
<input type="file" id="file-select-input" name="file" />
```

... things worked.

So why does the `name` attribute of an file input element need to be set for a file to be uploaded? According to the W3C specs, the `name` attribute assigns the control name, but what is the control name? Why is it important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to the W3C specs, the name attribute assigns the control name, but what is the control name? Why is it important?

The name of the form control controls the key in the key/value pairs that make up the POSTed data or the query string.

Without knowing the name of the control, there's no way to transform it into the data to be sent to the server.

Comment: ohhh... that makes sense. why wouldn't the ID of the element work? IDs are unique, names are not

Comment: Ah, but that's the point.  Think of checkboxes.  If you give them all the same name, that name will repeat multiple times in the submitted data -- one time for each checkbox, with the value in the submitted data being the `value` attribute on the input element.  Some form processors can then turn the multiple submissions into arrays (or similar language-specific constructs) either automatically or based on specific syntax.